# What's the difference between <pubDate> and <lastBuildDate> for a podcast rss feed?

Tags: rss, podcast

Can anyone familiar with creating *podcast* rss feeds please explain this one to me...

**Q:** What's the difference between `<pubDate>` and `<lastBuildDate>` for a podcast rss feed?

For context, `<pubDate>` and `<lastBuildDate>` are specific fields within an rss feed.

There are plenty of well-meaning descriptions available to research, e.g.

- http://rssboard.org/rss-specification
- [What is the difference between <pubDate> and <lastBuildDate> in RSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698076/what-is-the-difference-between-pubdate-and-lastbuilddate-in-rss)

Unfortunately, it is still confusing me.

Initially, I have tried to look at it from the point of view of a physical publication, e.g. a book.

- Book gets written = `<lastBuildDate>`
- Time elapses
- Book gets published = `<pubDate>`
- More time elapses, then, a new print run
- Book gets republished = `<pubDate>`
- More time elapes
- Author decides to update content = `<lastBuildDate>`
- Book gets republished = `<pubDate>`

This example makes perfect sense to me.  It works well for something with a physical copy.

However, how does that work for an electronic resource like a podcast?

With a podcast, when you create a new episode, or update the description, i.e. lastBuildDate, you also update the feed, i.e. pubDate. Usually at the same time.

Therefore, there appears to be no difference between `<pubDate>` and `<lastBuildDate>` for a podcast?‍♂️

Is there something I am missing / not understanding?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially, I have tried to look at it from the point of view of a physical publication, e.g. a book.

This is an excellent way to think about it. And you're correct. I don't think you should be confused by anything.

**To further clarify:**
1. The `lastBuildDate` can also be modified by the content generator (the code that creates the feed markup) if it internally modifies any metadata known only to itself.
2. As both fields are optional, you should not rely directly on them for detecting new content if that's your purpose. HTTP Cache related headers are better suited for this.
3. Even for non-podcast feeds, `pubDate` when available should be used IMO. Additionally also check for `pubdate`. Some feeds publish the lower-cased variant of it as well.

Comment: Thanks @dezinezync, that does help actually. I hadn't considered the idea of internal metadata updates - which are a perfectly valid reason for an updated lastBuildDate.

Excellent advice on not relying on them to be present also.